# How to create a Tab Bar Based program with 5 Views

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I am relatively new to ObjectiveC, but not with programming in which I have experience with both C and Python. I was wondering how to make an application that has a tab bar on the bottom, and five views all with labels and a certain amount of text on them. Then, also, I want to migrate an image on too one of the files and have audio on in the background. Does anyone know how to do this, and I am also open to suggestions that incorporate using C as part of the program.

Comment: ok now tell me on which xcode version you are working on?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this video tutorial](http://irockios.com/?p=32) and then just modify it to add in an extra couple of view controllers to connect to your `UITabBarController`.  I try to avoid using the Tab Bar template in XCode as you don't get an option to include the Core Data stack.  Even though you might not think you will use CD, it is nice to have it available, and starting with an empty application is much easier to work with IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Xcode and select file->new->new project->Tabbed Application

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to XCode/Objective C, I recommend that you create a new Project in XCode choosing "Tabbed application", play around and understand the project that loads.

When the project loads by default you will get 2 tabbar items only, but you can add more View Controllers and associate them with the Tab Bar Controller to have your total 5 views

You can also change image and text for each of the tabbar items based on your needs.

I think looking at this a Video tutoral : http://youtu.be/aorBSWbhGEE will be helpful to understand it quickly. You can search on Youtube for more similar videos